Userinit autolaunch C# Windows 10
I tried this code to add my program to \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon Userinit autolaunch in C# Windows 10. This is my code:

using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TempCode
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddToRegedit();
        }
        void AddToRegedit()
        {
            string programPath = @"C:\Users\XPS\Videos\TestApp.exe";
            RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", true);
            string newValue = @"C:\WINDOWS\system32\userinit.exe," + programPath + ",";
            key.SetValue("Userinit", newValue, RegistryValueKind.String);
            key.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Program added!");
        }
    }
}

I launched it with debug with admin privileges but nothing changed at all.
If you guys know what's going on please help me!
I tried : Restarting my OS, Launching program without debug, and even asking ChatGPT, but nothing changed.
Also If in cmd i write REG QUERY HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\ it says Error: Invalid syntax. Enter "REG QUERY /?" for usage help. Maybe that's because of space?

If you have a solution, then post it as the answer and accept it. Don't modify the question.

If you have arguments where you haveto deal with quoting use the ArgumentList instead, add each argument as it is and you will get the quoting for free

I fixed the problem myself here's the code:
void RegeditValueChange()
{
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "cmd",
        Arguments = "/k REG ADD \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon\" /v Userinit /t REG_SZ /d C:\\Path\\To\\Your\\File.exe /reg:64 /f"
        //Turn this 4 comments to execute cmd without window
        //UseShellExecute = false,
        //RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        //RedirectStandardError = true,
        //CreateNoWindow = true

    };
    using (Process process = Process.Start(processInfo))
    {
        process.WaitForExit();
        // Uncomment this for logging (if you execute without cmd window)
        /*string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();


        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(output))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Output: " + output);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + error);
        }*/
    }

}

So if you use 32 bit system just remove /reg:64. Also I don't recomend you to have spaces in the path to your program but, if you have, try adding "" at the beggining and at the end of your path. /f makes it not to ask for replacement
